# Is there a simpler way to do parsing in Java on Android?

Tags: android, parsing, dalvik

I'm having difficulty performing what should be a simple task.  Let's say I have a text file that states:

```
a = b
```

I want my program to read this file and output "b" whenever the user inputs "a". In Python or C++ I can accomplish this in around 7 lines or less.

However, I'm having difficulty finding a simple way to do this on Android.  For example, one sample that I found here on SO had nearly 900 lines in 6 files.

Is there a simple way to parse a file and return a variable on Android that I am missing?

Comment: The Gettysburg address is actually quite short, as it's ~20 lines with 80 char columns and a monospaced font.

Comment: Additionally, I would like this supposed answer on SO with 900 LOC. I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Sounds like you want to extract stuff from a file (see Anon's answer), then use a HashMap.

Comment: So where do you want the 'output' to be? In a TextView? On a button? In the status bar? Where's the 'file'? On the SD card? On a server somewhere? Android provides you with a framework for a GUI on a phone, you must expect an overhead that comes with that. It's not there for providing output to console apps

Comment: @Joe Please read through the FAQs at the top on the best way to construct a question.  You will get much better help if you phrase your question as an actual question with only technical details related to the question.  Please avoid whining and ranting.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more focused and less inflammatory. I think you'll find that you'll get a better response from other contributors using more objective wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're happy with the`a = b` format used in properties files, you get 99% of the way to your goal with

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(filename));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // the file is missing or is not in 'a = b' format
}
```

The, having got a variable `key` containing the string `"a"` from the user, the result of `properties.getProperty ( key )` will equal `"b"` if the file contains the line `a = b`. I'm pretty sure you need more than that in C++ to load a map from a file and handle all the escaping and character encoding issues.

If the properties are held in a text file called *mappings.properties* in the *assets* folder of your Android project rather than in the user's file system, then you get at it like this:

```
    final AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();
    final Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
        properties.load( am.open("mappings.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // the file is missing or is not in 'a = b' format
    }
```

This next bit is borrowed from the [android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText) to show a toast message with 'b' in it if 'a' is entered in the edit box. Maybe here is where you get your line count from, as setting up a GUI with XML files and adding listeners in Java is fairly verbose compared with other languages. That's due to Java and XML syntax rather than the virtual machine.

```
    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
              // Perform action on key press
              Toast.makeText(YourOuterViewClass.this, 
                  properties.getProperty(edittext.getText().toString()),
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
string s;
while(s = r.readLine()) {
    //Oh hey, I got a line out of the file.
    //In three lines of code.
    //So what's all this Android-bashing about?
}
```

Comment: +1 for the laugh. :) and of course, for a correct answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't need hundreds of lines of code to achieve this. It can be done in a few lines. I don't know what examples you were looking at but they were probably doing way more than what you are describing.